# Configure Child Component function to pass multiple params to Parent function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I configure a Child Components click event so that the Parent function can get the parameters required, sometimes the Parent function will require 1 param, sometimes 2 etc?

Child Component
**JS**

```
export default React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div class="ticker">
                <button class="ticker__tick ticker__tick--up btn btn--secondary state--bg" disabled={this.props.disabled ? this.props.disabled : false} onClick={() => this.props.handleClick('up')}>&nbsp;</button>
                <input class="ticker__value text--center soft-half flush--bottom" type="text" name="{this.props.tickerValueName}" value={this.props.value} readOnly />
                <button class="ticker__tick ticker__tick--down btn btn--secondary state--bg" disabled={this.props.disabled ? this.props.disabled : false} onClick={() => this.props.handleClick('down')}>&nbsp;</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

this.props.handleClick could point to `function(param1, param2)` or `function(param1)` etc

Answer (score 0):

Instead passing individual params, pass the entire params as an object and access the property of that object in the parent.

```
//parent
function handleClick(obj){
 var param1 = obj.param1
 var param2 = obj.param2
 ...
}

//children
onClick={() => this.props.handleClick({param1: 'down'})}
onClick={() => this.props.handleClick({param1: 'down', param2: 'up'})}
```

So, the number of parameters will always be one.

Hope this helps!